# ajax and asp.net OnClick clash

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a OnClick even on a image button and also a AJAX modualPopupExtender (from the ajax toolkit) the problem i have is that when i have the ModalPopupExtender acting on the image button it doesent fire the onClick event on the imageButton hers the code i have:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
                        TargetControlID="Image1" PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG">
                    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" OnClick="ImageButton_Click" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Upload-icon.png" />
                </ItemTemplate>
```

when i have this code the panel does popup but doesn't fire the onClick event, if i take out the ajax extender it fires the onclick event is they any way i can have both?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put another button with a CSS class so it doesn't show on the page (or style="display:none;" don't use visible=false or it won't work).

Then make the TargetControlID of your Modal Popup Extender to be your fake button.

Now you can handle the Click event of the ImageButton normally in your code behind, after doing the code that you want, call

```
ModalPopupExtender1.Show()
```

to show the popup.

Comment: i carnt call the ModalPopupExtender1 because its inside a <ItemTemplate> and it only exists inside that tag